# RadGrid filter does not open dropdown when clicked

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I am facing strange issue. I have added `RadGrid` to my web page and enabled its filtering and it was working perfect till i shutdown the system and came back another day. it stopped working and now when i click on the filter icon pages simply refreshes and drop down does not open up . I have spent full 2 days and have not find any fix.  Moreover i can see there is an error relates to `Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource` and its `"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing` ) after argument list"

Does this error relates to working of Filters ? What Filters needs to open dropdown ?

**Web Page**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="estimate_view.aspx.cs" Inherits="ePrint.Printcenter.Views.Estimate.estimate_view" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>

<form id="form1" runat="server">


<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">

</telerik:RadScriptManager>

                                        <telerik:RadGrid                                                 
                                            ID="GridView1" 
                                            runat="server" 
                                            AutoGenerateColumns="false"  
                                            AllowPaging="true" 
                                            AllowFilteringByColumn="true"
                                            OnSortCommand="GridView1_SortCommand" 
                                            OnItemCommand="GridView1_ItemCommand"
                                            OnColumnCreated="GridView1_ColumnCreated"
                                            OnNeedDataSource="GridView1_NeedDataSource"
                                            PagerStyle-AlwaysVisible="true"                                                 
                                            PageSize="50" 
                                            HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"> 
                                            <MasterTableView>                                                                                                  
                                            </MasterTableView>
                                        </telerik:RadGrid>

</form>
```

**CS Code**

```
protected void GridView1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    this.GridBind(this.CompanyID, this.UserID, this.GridView1.PageSize,   this.GridView1.CurrentPageIndex + 1, Convert.ToInt32(this.ddl_View.SelectedValue), estimate_view.SortedBy, estimate_view.sortdirection, estimate_view.WhereCondition);
}

public void GridBind(int CompanyID, int UserID, int PageSize, int PageNumber, int ViewID, string SortedBy, string SortDirection, string para)
{
    string empty = string.Empty;
    viewClass _viewClass = new viewClass();
    empty = _viewClass.ReturnFinalQueryForNewCustomView(CompanyID, UserID, PageSize, PageNumber, this.pg, ViewID, SortedBy, SortDirection, para);
    commonClass _commonClass = new commonClass();
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("PC_CustomizeView_Execute", _commonClass.openConnection())
    {
        CommandTimeout = 0,
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    };
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strSQL", empty);
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
    DataTable item = dataSet.Tables[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < item.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        item.Columns[i].ReadOnly = false;
    }
    if (item != null)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in item.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("CreatedDate"))
            {
                row["CreatedDate"] = this.objJava.Eprint_return_Date_Before_View(row["CreatedDate"].ToString(), CompanyID, UserID, false);
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("EstimateDate"))
            {
                row["EstimateDate"] = this.objJava.Eprint_return_Date_Before_View(row["EstimateDate"].ToString(), CompanyID, UserID, false);
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("OrderNumber"))
            {
                row["OrderNumber"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["OrderNumber"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("EstimateNumber"))
            {
                row["EstimateNumber"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["EstimateNumber"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("EstimateTitle"))
            {
                row["EstimateTitle"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["EstimateTitle"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("Estimator"))
            {
                row["Estimator"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["Estimator"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("Header"))
            {
                row["Header"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["Header"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("Footer"))
            {
                row["Footer"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["Footer"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("SalesPerson"))
            {
                row["SalesPerson"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["SalesPerson"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("StatusID"))
            {
                row["StatusID"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["StatusID"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("ReferredBY"))
            {
                row["ReferredBY"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["ReferredBY"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("Company"))
            {
                row["Company"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["Company"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("Greeting"))
            {
                row["Greeting"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["Greeting"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("CostCentre"))
            {
                row["CostCentre"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["CostCentre"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("CustomerID"))
            {
                row["CustomerID"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["CustomerID"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("AttentionID"))
            {
                row["AttentionID"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["AttentionID"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("CustomerAccountNumber"))
            {
                row["CustomerAccountNumber"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["CustomerAccountNumber"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("PaymentTerms"))
            {
                row["PaymentTerms"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["PaymentTerms"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("CompanyEmail"))
            {
                row["CompanyEmail"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["CompanyEmail"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("ContactEmail"))
            {
                row["ContactEmail"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["ContactEmail"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("ItemMaterial"))
            {
                row["ItemMaterial"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["ItemMaterial"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("ItemTitle"))
            {
                row["ItemTitle"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["ItemTitle"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("ItemDescription"))
            {
                row["ItemDescription"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["ItemDescription"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("ItemColour"))
            {
                row["ItemColour"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["ItemColour"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("ItemSize"))
            {
                row["ItemSize"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["ItemSize"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("ItemArtwork"))
            {
                row["ItemArtwork"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["ItemArtwork"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("ItemProofs"))
            {
                row["ItemProofs"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["ItemProofs"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("ItemDelivery"))
            {
                row["ItemDelivery"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["ItemDelivery"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("ItemFinishing"))
            {
                row["ItemFinishing"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["ItemFinishing"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("Itemterms_Instructions"))
            {
                row["Itemterms_Instructions"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["Itemterms_Instructions"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("ItemNotes"))
            {
                row["ItemNotes"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["ItemNotes"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("ItemPacking"))
            {
                row["ItemPacking"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["ItemPacking"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("EstimateStatus"))
            {
                row["EstimateStatus"] = this.objBase.SpecialDecode(row["EstimateStatus"].ToString());
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("ArtworkDate"))
            {
                row["ArtworkDate"] = this.objJava.Eprint_return_Date_Before_View(row["ArtworkDate"].ToString(), CompanyID, UserID, false);
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("ProofDate"))
            {
                row["ProofDate"] = this.objJava.Eprint_return_Date_Before_View(row["ProofDate"].ToString(), CompanyID, UserID, false);
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("ApprovalDate"))
            {
                row["ApprovalDate"] = this.objJava.Eprint_return_Date_Before_View(row["ApprovalDate"].ToString(), CompanyID, UserID, false);
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("ProductionDate"))
            {
                row["ProductionDate"] = this.objJava.Eprint_return_Date_Before_View(row["ProductionDate"].ToString(), CompanyID, UserID, false);
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("CompletionDate"))
            {
                row["CompletionDate"] = this.objJava.Eprint_return_Date_Before_View(row["CompletionDate"].ToString(), CompanyID, UserID, false);
            }
            if (!row.Table.Columns.Contains("DeliveryDate"))
            {
                continue;
            }
            row["DeliveryDate"] = this.objJava.Eprint_return_Date_Before_View(row["DeliveryDate"].ToString(), CompanyID, UserID, false);
        }
    }
    _commonClass.closeConnection();
    this.GridView1.DataSource = dataSet;
    if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count <= 0)
    {
        this.AddBoundColumns(dataSet.Tables[0], this.GridView1);
        this.div_Main.Style.Add("display", "block");
        this.GridView1.AllowCustomPaging = true;
        return;
    }
    this.AddBoundColumns(dataSet.Tables[0], this.GridView1);
    this.div_Main.Style.Add("display", "block");
    this.GridView1.AllowCustomPaging = true;
    this.GridView1.VirtualItemCount = Convert.ToInt32(dataSet.Tables[1].Rows[0][0].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show some code, e.g. from NeedDataSource event handler?

Also, note "[The built-in filtering feature is not supported when you bind the grid by explicitly calling DataBind()](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/functionality/filtering/overview) "

Comment: Yes its one line code in this event , i have added it please see the edited post.

Comment: without seeing the code of GridBind the above line is useless

Comment: ok, so you are not using DataBind() - that's good. Are there any client-side functions (javascript) on the page?

Comment: Nope .. there is no script at client side. it just stopped working and i am sure i did not change anything in code. if i know what is needed to run filter menu then i think i can figure it out ?

Comment: Hammad, is your problem solved? What was solution. I am facing simillar issue.